# Securely storing data, how do apps do it?

Tags: ios

I'm doing some research on a new project we want to work on, but before we actually take on the project I have some concerns.

This project involves storing a lot of (text) data somewhere on a server, you can think about it like Instagram (but without photos).
So you can follow people, view profiles, list of activity ...

The question is, how do these apps send all this data securely to a server?
And what kind of server do they use? Something like Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are sent over https which is built into the [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. You can have a server (I use linux but you can use anything) have a self signed ssl certificate and your App code can give an exception to that particular URL for self signed certificates if you are wanting to save money. It is better practice and more secure to have a signed certificate though.

As far as storing it, most don't actually store it encrypted. It is sent to the server running a web service encrypted and then is stored in the database / file system unencrypted. The reason for this is there is a lot of processing power required to compress things and the extra over head of storing encrypted things as well as making it harder to search and index depending on how you do it.

Amazon AWS would work although I run my own server at home. It's quite easy to set up.

Comment: Ok, so basically sending all your data over a secure connection?
Most of the apps I've build use an API, so I don't have much experience with setting up my own server for data transfers. It's not that the data is very large, but still.

Comment: What API's have you used? What programming languages have you used?

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with PHP, that would've been my first guess to do it with that.

Comment: PHP will work fine. Connect it to a MySQL database and just think of the App viewing a web page via a URL, except it is a structured form of data like XML or JSON. You can purchase a reasonably set up https instance from most web hosting companies and concentrate on the App code talking over https to your PHP code. Make sure you send all data via POST (encrypted) not GET (not encrypted) and sanitise all data going into your db. After you get the basics you can have a look at REST or SOAP.